# Possible to detect apple watch to apple watch contact via NFC?

Tags: ios, nfc, apple-watch

If yes then how ?
If no then is there an other way to detect close contact ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple does not provide an API and [explicitly](http://www.cultofmac.com/296093/apple-confirms-iphone-6-nfc-apple-pay/) stated that NFC was only for Apple Pay but there is possibility that it will be opened up in the future. You can, however, use bluetooth to detect nearby devices.

Comment: Link to nearfield bluetooth detection ? :D